# Исполнение кода на STM32 , полученного с ПК

Tags: stm32, интерпретатор

Есть задача получать код в виде JSON с ПК, парсить его и,собственно, исполнять.Одно дело, когда нужно помигать светодиодом.Можно послать с ПК ключевое слово, по которому выполнится функция мигания светодиода и даже можно ее доработать, чтобы в принимаемых параметрах была задержка и количество морганий. Но вот когда дело доходит до большого количества взаимосвязанных действий с условиями и циклами, я теряюсь. Как это описать в контроллере. Например, если сработал датчик, поморгать светодиодом. Нужно какой-то интерпретатор ставить, вроде forth, или есть простое решение для это задачи?

Comment: Проблема более высокого уровня. Просто отправить команды, по которым исполнится код в МК -  это одно. А вот отправлять условия, по которым этот код должен выполняться, совсем другое. Для меня, по крайней мере.

Comment: Код, который завернут в JSON, он что из себя представляет? Или это тоже на ваше усмотрение? Какой-нибудь наглядный пример бы помог.

Comment: Насколько я понял вам нужно - 1.Распарсить JSON. 2. Определится с командами (в т ч с условными командами). 3. Написать исполнительную часть для команд. Верно? В чём собственно проблема? Или вы хотиме прям таки "простенький" компилятор?

Comment: К сожалению, это пока только в моей голове . JSON в данном случае не важен. Важно, можно ли с помощью каких-то внешних команд и кода в МК описать условия и циклы.

Comment: Возможно. Массив комманд. Массив данных. Можно реализавать двумя массивами. Можно одним. Почитайте "конечные автоматы"

Comment: Проблема в том, что я могу написать код и команды для обьектов(светодиода , датчика), но не понимаю как написать универсальный код для условий ,вроде if() и тд. а ведь может быть if внутри if 'a

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с понятием - конечный автомат.  Теория - http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82 практика http://habr.com/ru/post/241941/

Comment: Я писал автоматы на МК и на ПЛИС. Представьте,что мне нужно выполнить код с произвольным количеством циклов и условий, притом еще наличием вложенных условий и циклов.Эта задача разве решаема с помощью автоматов?

Comment: Да.эта задача решается с помощью конечного автомата. Программу для него - загружаете из JSON. В том или ином виде вам понадобится состояние (или массив состояний, если будет рекурсия или вложеные процедуры). Массив комманд и массив данных. И большой switch или case или if для выполнения разных комманд.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Буду разбираться.

Comment: Конечно если есть "интерпретаторы" для stm32 хотя бы perl, а лучше javascript - то конечно проще в интерпретатор загрузить - там всё это есть... но мне кажется что для stm32 нету в свободном доступе готового хорошего интерпретатора. А писать свой... по сути интерпретатор тоже конечный автомат - но немного сложнее (лексические разборы синтаксиз связывание и т д).

Comment: Ещё хабр http://habr.com/ru/post/345960/

Comment: @nick_n_a, точно есть micropython и javascript

Comment: Тогда.... второй вариант - как-то преобразовать JSON в скрипт - скомпилировать - и отправить на выполнение. Ресурсы... соответственно.